# How do I extract dates from .rtf in R

Tags: r, regex, date

I have articles in .rtf from which I want to extract the dates. The article looks like this:

[image]

The first line is the title, followed by a blank line. Then it lists the following, each on its own line:

- The number of words
- The date
- The news agency
- The news agency's acronymn
- The language
- Copyright information

I have tried the following code but it doesn't seem to work. Seems like the problem is in the one to extract the date.

```
##First I read the file using this code: 
htmlText <- read_file(paste("/Users/adhyantarahma/Desktop/Factiva-20190905-0316.rtf"))

##then I removed new lines tags
removeNewLines <- gsub("\n"," ",htmlText) 

##and I changed " to ' in text
cleanLines <- gsub("\"", "'", removeNewLines) 

print(cleanLines)

##the relevant part of cleanLines look like this 
#\\ 347 words\\ 9 April 2016\\ FARS News Agency\\ FARSNA\\ English\\

##then I used this to extract date 
date <- str_extract_all(htmlText, "words \\d{1,2} [A-Z][a-z]+ \\d{4}")[[1]]
```

But it doesn't seem to pick up the date. When I run it, it always says that there is no character.

What should I do so that I can pick up the date?

Answer (score 0):

I'm just following your solution and turning it into a solution with slight modification.

```r
library(readr)
library(stringr)
htmlText <- read_file("Factiva-20190905-0316.rtf")


# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
              # output -- htmlText
# [1] "347 words\n9 April 2016\nFARS News Agency\nFARSNA\nEnglish\n"

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------

#replace "\n" with a space   
removeNewLines <- gsub("\n"," ",htmlText) 

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
            # output -- removeNewLines
# [1] "347 words 9 April 2016 FARS News Agency FARSNA English "

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------

       # extract the date from removedNewLines
my_date <- str_extract_all(removeNewLines, "\\d{1,2} [A-Z][a-z]+ \\d{4}")[[1]]
        # output -- my_date
#[1] "9 April 2016"

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
```