# How to extract different articles from a single text file?

Tags: r, regex, rtf

I have an .rtf /.txt file which collects newspaper articles.
[The .rtf file can be found here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/f7bt7je7intizez/bild_afd_all.rtf?dl=0). [And the .txt file can be found here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/a6v1o5yaic9ugfp/bild_afd_all.txt?dl=0).

I would like to extract the (1) Date, (2) Title and (3) Body of the articles. In the end, I would like to have a dataframe in which each row is an article, and there are three columns for the title, date and body. As I make clear in [this screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j9a18fyv0pmfwmr/Screenshot%202021-08-28%20at%2011.42.53.png?dl=0), the title is the sentence in bold (underlined in yellow here), and the body is the several paragraphs underneath (in the blue square here).

I have managed to extract the dates using regex. However, I've been unable to extract the titles and the bodies of the articles.

**Would it be possible to extract the Titles and Bodies of the articles from this .rtf /.txt using regular expressions?**

I used the following code:

```
library(readr)
library(stringr)
htmlText <- read_file("bild_afd_all.rtf")

#replace "\n" with a space   
removeNewLines <- gsub("\n"," ",htmlText) 
removeNewLines

# 1. extract the DATE from removedNewLines
date <- str_extract_all(removeNewLines, "\\d{1,2} [A-Z][a-z]+ \\d{4}")[[1]]

# 2. extract the TITLE from removedNewLines 
## how?


# 3. extract the BODY from removedNewLines
## how?
```

*This question is related to this previously answered one: [How do I extract dates from .rtf in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57833072/how-do-i-extract-dates-from-rtf-in-r) In that post, regular expressions were used to extract dates from an .rtf file. That file was a collection of newspaper articles.*

Many, many thanks in advance!

Comment: It would be easier if you provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Could you share the rtf file.

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I have now shared the .rtf file - please see the original post. And thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, some sample data would actually be useful.
However, I recommend doing the following:

1. Load the R file (I generated an example substitute in the txt variable)
2. Delete blank lines
3. Find the word count indexes
4. Based on these indexes, draw all the rest that interest you.

I assume that the structure is the same and that the text of the article always starts 9 lines below the word count.

See my code.

```
library(tidyverse)
#1
txt = c("title1", "", "12   words", "12-12-2004", "BILD", "ZBILD", "BIBU", 
        "2", "295", "German", "Copyright", "first bla bla bla", "bla bla bla", "bla bla bla", 
        "bla bla bla", "bla bla bla", "bla bla bla", "bla bla bla", "bla bla bla", 
        "bla bla bla", "bla bla bla", "bla bla bla", "bla bla bla", "bla bla bla", 
        "bla bla bla", "bla bla bla", "bla bla bla", "bla bla bla", "bla bla bla", 
        "bla bla bla", "last bla bla bla", "", "", "", "", "", "title2", "", 
        "", "12    words", "10-12-2004", "BILD", "ZBILD", "BIBU", "2", "1235", 
        "German", "Copyright", "first da da da", "da da da", "da da da", "da da da", "da da da", 
        "da da da", "da da da", "da da da", "da da da", "da da da", "da da da", 
        "da da da", "da da da", "last da da da", "", "", "", "title3", "", 
        "", "12   words", "10-12-2004", "BILD", "ZBILD", "BIBU", "2", "1235", 
        "German", "Copyright", "first info info", "info info", "info info", "info info", "info info", 
        "info info", "info info", "info info", "last info info")

#2
txt = txt[txt!=""] 
#3
idx_word = which(str_detect(txt, "[0-9]+ +words$"))


fart = function(txt, idx_word){
  out = rep("", length(idx_word))
  for(i in 1:length(idx_word)){
    if(i<length(idx_word)){
      idx_txt=(idx_word[i]+9):(idx_word[i+1]-2)
    } else{
      idx_txt=(idx_word[i]+9):length(txt)
    }
  out[i]=paste(txt[idx_txt], collapse="\n")
  }
  out
}

#4
df = tibble(
  title = txt[idx_word-1],
  date = txt[idx_word+1],
  article = fart(txt, idx_word)
)
```

output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  title  date       article                                  
  <chr>  <chr>      <chr>                                    
1 title1 12-12-2004 "first bla bla bla\nbla bla bla\nbla bla~
2 title2 10-12-2004 "first da da da\nda da da\nda da da\nda ~
3 title3 10-12-2004 "first info info\ninfo info\ninfo info\n~
```

Please adjust it as needed

Here is the new version of the program.
Unfortunately, in terms of thoroughly cleaning your text into formatting strings, you will have to play on your own. I don't know if you need it or not. The same goes for converting diacritics to UTF-8, line breaks, new page etc.

This is only a general recipe for how to do this. As you can see below it works. You have to do the rest on your own.

```
library(fs)
library(tidyverse)

readTxt = function(FileName){
  lines = character()
  if(fs::file_exists(FileName)){
    con = file(FileName, open = "r")
    on.exit(close(con))
    lines = readLines(con)
  }
  lines
}

remove_f2_b = function(txt)  txt = str_replace(txt, "\\\\f2\\\\b ", "")
remove_f1_b0 = function(txt)  txt = str_replace(txt, "\\\\f1\\\\b0 ", "")
remove_f1_fs20 = function(txt)  txt = str_replace(txt, "\\\\f1\\\\fs20 ", "")
remove_f0_fs24 = function(txt)  txt = str_replace(txt, "\\\\f0\\\\fs24 ", "")
remove_cf0 = function(txt)  txt = str_replace(txt, "\\\\cf0 ", "")

remove_format = function(txt) txt %>% remove_f2_b() %>% remove_f1_b0 %>% 
  remove_f1_fs20() %>% remove_f0_fs24() %>% remove_cf0

txt = suppressWarnings(readTxt("bild_afd_all.rtf")) %>% remove_format()
txt = txt[txt!=""] 
txt = txt[txt!="\\"] 
view(txt)
#3
idx_word = which(str_detect(txt, "\\d?\\,?\\d+ words\\\\$"))


fart = function(txt, idx_word){
  out = rep("", length(idx_word))
  for(i in 1:length(idx_word)){
    if(i<length(idx_word)){
      idx_txt=(idx_word[i]+9):(idx_word[i+1]-2)
    } else{
      idx_txt=(idx_word[i]+9):length(txt)
    }
    out[i]=paste(txt[idx_txt], collapse="\n")
  }
  out
}



#4
df = tibble(
  title = txt[idx_word-1],
  date = str_replace(txt[idx_word+1], "\\\\$", ""),
  article = fart(txt, idx_word)
)

head(df)
```

output

```
  title                                                      date             article                                          
  <chr>                                                      <chr>            <chr>                                            
1 "Exklusiv-Umfrage; SO DENKEN DIE DEUTSCHEN \\'dcER PEGIDA" 18 December 2014 "Berlin - Immer mehr Zulauf f\\'fc die sogenannt~
2 "Seite 2"                                                  18 December 2014 "Berlin - Endlich mehr Geld im Portemonnaie: Die~
3 "Ex-Minister Friedrich greift Kanzlerin an"                29 December 2014 "Berlin - Wieder Kurs-Debatten in der Union! Ex-~
4 "Seite 4"                                                  29 December 2014 "KOMMENTAR\\\nVon FRITZ ESSER Zusatzbeitrag, Dur~
5 "Wegen Pegida-Schelte; AUSLAND FEIERT MERKEL"              2 January 2015   "Berlin - \"Ich sage allen, die auf solche Demon~
6 "Seite 2"                                                  2 January 2015   "Von\\\nHANNO KAUTZ u. RALF SCHULER\\\nBerlin - ~
```

**Version for txt files**

```
library(fs)
library(tidyverse)

readTxt = function(FileName){
  lines = character()
  if(fs::file_exists(FileName)){
    con = file(FileName, open = "r")
    on.exit(close(con))
    lines = readLines(con)
  }
  lines
}

txt = suppressWarnings(readTxt("bild_afd_all.txt")) 
txt = txt[txt!=""] 
txt = txt[txt!=" "] 
view(txt)
#3
idx_word = which(str_detect(txt, "\\d?\\,?\\d+ words$"))


fart = function(txt, idx_word){
  out = rep("", length(idx_word))
  for(i in 1:length(idx_word)){
    if(i<length(idx_word)){
      idx_txt=(idx_word[i]+9):(idx_word[i+1]-2)
    } else{
      idx_txt=(idx_word[i]+9):length(txt)
    }
    out[i]=paste(txt[idx_txt], collapse="\n")
  }
  out
}



#4
df = tibble(
  title = txt[idx_word-1],
  date = str_replace(txt[idx_word+1], "\\\\$", ""),
  article = fart(txt, idx_word)
)

head(df, 10)
```

output

```
# A tibble: 10 x 3
   title                                                   date             article                                                                            
   <chr>                                                   <chr>            <chr>                                                                              
 1 "Exklusiv-Umfrage; SO DENKEN DIE DEUTSCHEN ĂśER PEGIDA" 18 December 2014 "Berlin - Immer mehr Zulauf fĂĽ die sogenannten Pegida-Demonstrationen in Dresden ~
 2 "Seite 2"                                               18 December 2014 "Berlin - Endlich mehr Geld im Portemonnaie: Die verfĂĽbaren Einkommen der deutsch~
 3 "Ex-Minister Friedrich greift Kanzlerin an"             29 December 2014 "Berlin - Wieder Kurs-Debatten in der Union! Ex-Innenminister Hans-Peter Friedrich~
 4 "Seite 4"                                               29 December 2014 "KOMMENTAR\nVon FRITZ ESSER Zusatzbeitrag, Durchschnittsbeitrag, Sonderbeitrag - M~
 5 "Wegen Pegida-Schelte; AUSLAND FEIERT MERKEL"           2 January 2015   "Berlin - \"Ich sage allen, die auf solche Demonstrationen gehen: Folgen Sie denen~
 6 "Seite 2"                                               2 January 2015   "Von\nHANNO KAUTZ u. RALF SCHULER\nBerlin - Exakt 118 Stufen sind es bis in den se~
 7 "ROLF KLEINE   "                                        3 January 2015   "Von\nROLF KLEINE\nAlle Jahre wieder ...\nDie Forderung aus der CSU, abgelehnte As~
 8 " AfD -Spitze lĂ¤t Pegida-Vertreter in Landtag ein"     3 January 2015   "Dresden - Es wird ein brisantes Treffen: AfDCo-Chefin Frauke Petry (39) lud Vertr~
 9 "Seite 2"                                               3 January 2015   "Koblenz - Im Stadtrat von Koblenz kracht es krĂ¤tig! Anlass ist die geplante Wied~
10 " AfD -Spitze fĂĽchtet Zerfall der Partei"              5 January 2015   "Berlin - Der Machtkampf in der AfD-Spitze wird immer hĂ¤ter, die FĂĽrung hĂ¤t ein~
>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have now attached the .rtf file to the original post. As I think you will see, its format is a bit different to how you imagined. As a result, I don't think your suggestion would work with it. Many thanks in advance if you could look at the .rtf file and consider how to do this.

Comment: Fred, you will find a modified version of my program at the top. As you can see it works. However, this is a general recipe that you will have to adapt to your needs. Now you have to put some effort into it. However, I showed you which one to follow.

Comment: Dear Marek, thank you so much! Having instead used a .txt instead of an .rtf file, however, I receive this error message: "Error in (idx_word[i] + 9):length(txt) : NA/NaN argument". I think a .txt file could be preferable, as it avoids a lot of the strange formatting issues. I will attach the .txt file in the original post. Perhaps you could take a look at that. Again, thank you so much, I greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: Hi Fred. In response, I have included a version for the txt files. It really doesn't differ much from the rtf version. You have to put some effort into building your own programs.

Comment: I would be grateful if your appreciation of my work was expressed in accepting the correct solution.

Comment: Thank you so much, Marek! Your help is greatly, greatly appreciated.